# How to enable tc command when building a kernel using Yocto recipes

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, iproute

I want to enable [tc command](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/tc.8.en.html) that comes in [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) on my linux kernel. My kernel is built using yocto and bitbake.

So, I copied the iproute recipes and whole directory from the following link to try --
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/recipes-connectivity/iproute2

And included in my yocto build. That picked up recipe and built it all well. But I `tc` command is still not available on the built kernel.

**Question:**
What am I missing and how to enable `tc` in the kernel of a linux image built using Yocto recipes?

Comment: You need to specify `DEPENDS += iproute2` in your kernel recipe. So that all the files of iproute is available during kernel compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to copy the whole recipe, poky should be in your sources directory. So just reference the recipe in your image. You need *both* iproute2 *and* iproute2-tc.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "iproute2 \
        iproute2-tc"
```

Additionally you may need to enable some kernel modules that `tc` make use of, depending on your needs:

```
CONFIG_NET_SCHED
CONFIG_NET_SCH_CBQ
CONFIG_NET_SCH_HTB
CONFIG_NET_SCH_HFSC
CONFIG_NET_SCH_ATM
CONFIG_NET_SCH_PRIO
CONFIG_NET_SCH_MULTIQ
CONFIG_NET_SCH_RED
CONFIG_NET_SCH_SFQ
CONFIG_NET_SCH_TEQL
CONFIG_NET_SCH_TBF
CONFIG_NET_SCH_GRED
CONFIG_NET_SCH_DSMARK
CONFIG_NET_SCH_NETEM
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS
```