# Enable 'tc' of iproute2 package on YOCTO

Tags: yocto, imx6, iproute

We're trying to enable Traffic Control (`tc`) on YOCTO (warrior dist.), while it seems that `tc` was indeed built into the YOCTO image, when trying to apply a `tc filter` command we're getting this error:

> Error: TC classifier not found

This is the full command that I'm trying:

`tc filter add dev ${interface} protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst ${board_ip} match ip dport ${dport} 0xffff flowid 1:${port_id}`

Before that I issue a `tc qdisc` and `tc class` commands that are okay.

The kernel that I'm using is 4.19.35-imx8mq+g82acfd1 and it's built (`make modules_prepare all`)

Thanks in advance!
Nadav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable `tc` we've followed the guidelines in this article:[How to enable tc command when building a kernel using Yocto recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669185/how-to-enable-tc-command-when-building-a-kernel-using-yocto-recipes)

But as it turns out, in addition to this, one would need to make sure that the specific filters that are going to be used are also enabled. In my case it I needed to enable also `NET_CLS_U32` option.